# Chapter title WITHOUT number in heading

Tags: header-footer

I would like to create a header that looks like the one below (No need for colouring though). So far I have only managed the "Chapter 1 | " part and not the title. How do I get LaTeX to print the chapter title? I'm using a two sided document in the report class. (code example provided)

I'm sorry if this question has already been answered, but I have searched for a long time without finding an answer. Thanks for the help.

[image: header]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\begin{document}

\def\layout{2}  

\ifnum\layout=2 
    \fancyhf{}      
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
    \fancyhead[LE]{\nouppercase{\chaptername~ \thechapter~ |}}
    \fancyhead[RO]{\nouppercase{ \rightmark}}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{         
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}    
 \else          
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhf{}                  
    \fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{ \leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fi


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What exactly should be without number?

Answer (score 1):

Something similar

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,openright,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}
{\centering\normalfont\Huge}
{\color{green!20!black!70}
  \chaptertitlename\ \thechapter\ \color{black}\rule [-0.3em]{1pt}{\baselineskip} }
{0pt}
{\vspace{1pc}\Huge}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I propose this variant, with a slight spacing asymmetry  around the vertical rule:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, openright, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filcenter\normalfont\Huge}
{\color{ForestGreen}
  \chaptertitlename\space\thechapter\ \rule [-0.3em]{2pt}{\baselineskip} }
{0.33em}
{\color{black}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `patchcmd` from `etoolbox` package, as follows. Put in the preamble the command :

```
\makeatletter
\AfterEndPreamble{
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\raggedright }{\centering }{\typeout{centering OK}}{\typeout{centering failed}} % centered title
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\par\nobreak\vskip 20\p@}{\relax}{\typeout{sameline OK}}{\typeout{sameline failed}} %same line
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp\space}{{\Huge\@chapapp}\space}{\typeout{Huge chap OK}}{\typeout{Huge chap OK}} % enlargee chattername
 \patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\Huge\bfseries\thechapter\space |\space }{\typeout{format OK}}{\typeout{format failed}}
}
\makeatother
```

Works with `hyperref` and with `babel`

Note : the `\typeout`s print a message in the console and log, and could be suppressed if everything works.

However, if you want to hack the sectioning commands, the standard package is `titlesec` (tough it sometimes conflict with `minitoc`.

Result :[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using the `titlesec` package.

```
\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before-code}[after-code]
```

See [here](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) for more information.